# Twitter API - how to get real time tweets by user

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Is there a way to pull real time tweets using [`Tweepy`](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/) by Twitter handle or Twitter ID?

I've tried using the [`Twitter Streaming API`](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview) but I'm only able to get tweets filtered by keywords:

```
import tweepy
import json

# Import the necessary methods from tweepy library
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

# Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API 
access_token = "INSERT ACCESS TOKEN"
access_token_secret = "INSERT ACCESS TOKEN SECRET"
consumer_key = "INSERT CONSUMER KEY"
consumer_secret = "INSERT CONSUMER SECRET"

# This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This handles Twitter authentication and connection to Twitter Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=['european central bank'])
```

Is there anyway I can pull down tweets by Twitter username?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to pass the [`follow`](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter) keyword like this:

```
stream.filter(follow=['user_id'])
```

It receives a list of user IDs.

From the [`API`](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#follow) docs, this should return:

- Tweets created by the user.
- Tweets which are retweeted by the user.
- Replies to any Tweet created by the user.
- Retweets of any Tweet created by the user.
- Manual replies, created without pressing a reply button (e.g. “@twitterapi I agree”).

It doesn't return:

- Tweets mentioning the user (e.g. “Hello @twitterapi!”).
- Manual Retweets created without pressing a Retweet button (e.g. “RT @twitterapi The API is great”).
- Tweets by protected users.

**Note**
You can specify both `track` and `follow` values and it will result in tweets with the input keyword *or* tweets created by the input user.

Comment: Hey Forge, is there any way to tap into Protected Users?

Comment: How to get only the tweets created by the original user, no other things (retweets, etc.)?